# FEAL-4 Linear Cryptanalysis - Prevention

Tags: s-boxes, linear-cryptanalysis, feal

currently, I prepare for an exam about cryptanalysis. In class, we talked about linear cryptanalysis for FEAL-4. We constructed four linear equations, extended them to equations for three rounds and then applied a Brut Force search in order to find the keys of every round.

My question is as follows: **How can I prevent such an attack?**

My idea: I think, it is necessary to replace the S-Boxes of FEAL with 'better' S-Boxes? Such that, it is not possible to find relationships between input and output bits of the S-boxes (and therefore, also for the whole F-Function). But how does such an 'good' S-Box look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention:

- LC = Linear Cryptanalysis
- DC = Differential Cryptanalysis

---

There are multiple ways to increase the security of a block cipher.

The first one (and usually applied) is to increase the number of rounds. In the case of FEAL, they switched from 4 to 8 rounds and then to X rounds. Therefore you would have to extend the equations for 7+ rounds before starting your brute force attack (see table below from [Handbook of applied Crypto](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), note that the time indicated is not correct anymore due to the book being written in 1996...)

```
+---------------+------------------------+----------------+-----------------+
|               |                        |                |                 |
|  Attack       |    Data complexity     |   storage      |  procesing      |
|  Method       |                        | complexity     |  complexity     |
|               | known   |  chosen      |                |                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   FEAL-4-LC   |   5     |              |    30K bytes   |   6 minutes     |
|   FEAL-6-LC   |  100    |              |   100K bytes   |  40 minutes     |
|   FEAL-8-LC   |  2^24   |              |                |  10 minutes     |
|   FEAL-8-DC   |         | 2^7  pairs   |  280K bytes    |   2 minutes     |
|   FEAL-16-DC  |         | 2^29 pairs   |                | 2^30 operations |
|   FEAL-24-DC  |         | 2^45 pairs   |                | 2^46 operations |
|   FEAL-32-DC  |         | 2^66 pairs   |                | 2^67 operations |
+---------------+---------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

In the case of Linear cryptanalysis, the linear equations/approximations used to break the cipher holds with a certain probability. You *just* have to make sure that this probability stays low.

It has been [shown by Joan Daemen and Vincent Rijmen in *The Design of Rijndael: AES*, chapter 7](http://jda.noekeon.org/#RijndaelBook) that LC and DC share similarities by the Walsh-Hadamard transform. Increasing the DC resistance of an algorithm also increases the LC resistance.

The idea is therefore to find a *good* S-box, you need to prove that the Differentials don't go over a certain probability (the lower the better). In the case of Rinjdael (AES), they use a $8$ bit S-box. Therefore the table of the differentials has $2^8 = 256$ rows and columns. By analyzing such table, they made sure that no differential probabilities goes over $\frac{4}{256}$.

The bigger the S-box, the harder the differentials will be to exploit. However, it is also required from the designer to prove the security of his algorithm. So increasing the size of the S-box also make the proof harder. This is the reason why the $\chi$ function of keccak is similar to a 5 bit s-box.

Smaller S-box implies higher probabilities right ? Therefore, we add a diffusion layer. The goal is to propagate the differences and make them harder to track. There you have two kind of strategies: weak alignment or strong alignment... But that is getting too far.

I would suggest to have a look at this presentation [Two ways of building round functions for block ciphers by J. Daemen](http://summerschool-croatia.cs.ru.nl/2016/slides/JoanDaemen_June%209.pdf).